# Lightning-input date when marked required is showing required error after date selection

Tags: lightning-web-components

The problem is that the date input life cycle is as such:

1. onfocus on input brings up the date picker
2. on date selection it will populate the date on the input
3. onblur will be called with validation check (by that time the onchange hasn't kicked in yet)
4. required error shows (because the on change hasn't happened yet and the value is not updated)
5. onchange event is called and updates value
6. onblur removes the error because now it has a value

here is what I mean:

[image]

here is my markup:

```
<lightning-input type="date" name="input5" label="Required date field" required ></lightning-input>
```

here is a gif:

[image]

any workarounds or suggestions how to call onchange before validation occurs ?

Comment: I'm not seeing this problem with this in the [Playground](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/ZC3VGqSaH/1/edit). Can you please [edit] your question to demonstrate what you're doing specifically that's the problem?

Comment: @sfdcfox, I have uploaded an image but to be more precise what happens is that on selecting a date the onchange event happens after blur for some reason so if you have any validation on the input it will trigger the error even though the value shows on the input.

Comment: can you also share the js ?

Comment: @User6670, so I just checked again and literarily just chuck the example as it is from the the Sales force developer docs   into the template and you can see the issue no js needed: <lightning-input type="date" name="input5" label="Required date field" required ></lightning-input>

Comment: are you talking about  the scenario when there is already an error "the field is required" and then you change the date you have to click outside to kick the validation and remove the error

Comment: @User6670, no , this is when you start fresh , I have attached a gif with the scenario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use  reportValidity() function to report validity on change.though dont know why is it happening.

```
  <template>
    <lightning-input
    type="date"
    required
    name='input1'
    message-when-value-missing="This field is required"
    label="enter date"
    onchange={handleChange}
    ></lightning-input>
</template>
```

and in js

```
   handleChange(){
        console.log('change event');
        var inp=this.template.querySelector('lightning-input');
        if(inp.name='input1'){
            inp.reportValidity();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for that, that does the trick but its still a mystery as to why its happening...

Comment: @OranJacob  yeah correct it also does not happens in pg https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/ZC3VGqSaH/3/edit